# Oracle SQL grouped row already exist inserted

Tags: sql, oracle

I load data periodically and I want to insert group only if it is not inserted yet.

Sample:

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3
------------------
1    | A    | 1
2    | A    | 1
3    | A    | 1
4    | B    | 2
1    | B    | 2
5    | B    | 2
```

COL1 is unique identifier, COL2 is some classification and COL3 is group identifier. Here 1,2 and 3(COL1) are group 1(COL3) because they are part of A (COL2). Similarly for group 2 (COL3)

In next load I have

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3
------------------
1    | D    | 1
2    | D    | 1
3    | D    | 1
4    | B    | 3
1    | B    | 3
5    | C    | 4
```

Here 1,2 and 3 (COL1) again are group 1(COL3), but 4 (COL1) is group 3(COL3) because group 2(COL3) in prev load is for 4 and 5 to be part of B(COL2).

**Values in COL2 are not important. Important is that 1,2 and 3 are from one class.**

Maybe my explanation is not clean, but with my try to do that the idea must be cleaner.

I tried LISTAGG on COL1 with partition by COL2 and that is COL3.

In prev example:

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3
------------------
1    | A    | 1,2,3
2    | A    | 1,2,3
3    | A    | 1,2,3
4    | B    | 1,4,5
5    | B    | 1,4,5
1    | B    | 1,4,5
```

And

```
COL1 | COL2 | COL3
------------------
1    | D    | 1,2,3
2    | D    | 1,2,3
3    | D    | 1,2,3
4    | B    | 1,4
1    | B    | 1,4
5    | C    | 5
```

This mark of group work fine, but i have groups with length more than 4000(**LISTAGG doesn't support so long strings**).

Next I try to use CLOB and compare ORA_HASH values, but ORA_HASH value return "random" values for every CLOB(**on every execute for same clob's content return different valu**e). It is important to keep unique identifiers(COL1) that are part of group because I have to restore them(just a note, this is not part of question).

I thing about using detail table but I don't know how to do that.

I read about DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH but I search for different solution.

In the result is enough to have unique ID of group and participants of group (or they to be inserted somewhere and to have FK to this row of this unique identifier)

ADDED NOTE

Task can be translated as mark team. There is no matter which is the game(COL2) that they are play. But when they change team member's list, I have to give new identifier. That I forgot to add(and will edit in example) is that one member(col1) can be part of more than one team(COL3). I want to keep teams identifiers and after time when I load again this team do not insert it and do not gave new unique identifier. When I combination (1,2,3) is loaded for first time (is not inserted wet) I use sequence and create new **group ID**. That I need is some unique identifier (like a case with list LISTAGG) to check do i have this group inserted.

Now I store groups (group ID, members_list) in table. **members_list** is used when I load data next time to check there is this team inserted and if not I insert sequence.NEXTVAL and **members_list**. Problem is that **members_list** in some cases is langer than 4000 chars (max length of varchar2)

Comment: What are you trying to insert, and what is a case where it should not be allowed?

Comment: I added notes to my post because comment was too long.

Comment: `COL1` can't possibly be a unique identifier, so I think that I need clarification on that point, for starters.

Comment: COL1 is person id. One person can be part of more than one team. COL2 is like GAME. One game can be play from one team aka COL1 and COL2 are PERSON - GAME pairs. All persons playing same game are TEAM (COL3 or unique identifier that I search).

Comment: Oh, I see - I was looking at your sample tables from the wrong perspective. I'm just not entirely sure what your end objective is here. Is your goal simply to have a result set where `COL3` looks like `1,2,3`, `1,4`, and so on?